# Jest "Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using jest with the Vue framework, to write unite tests. My example test is passing but I am having an error logging the request. How do I fix this issue? Am I using async incorrectly in jest? A copy of the test is below with the error farther down below.

**Test**

```
describe('Home', () => {
    test('Example Test', async () => {
        // Arrange - Mounts the component so we can test it. And chooses what we are going to test in the component
        const wrapper = mount(Home2)
        // Act - Does something to the component

        // Assert - Checks to see if what we did to the component matches what we want it to do
        expect(wrapper.html()).toContain(0)
    })
})
```

**Error with test passing**

```
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.324 s
Ran all test suites.

  ●  Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
    Attempted to log "Get Error:  Error: Network Error
        at createError (/home/user/Documents/Code/RRMEC/src/frontend/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
        at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (/home/user/Documents/Code/RRMEC/src/frontend/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:84:14)
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. You omitted the unit that you test. The error means that you perform real requests, which is a mistake for unit tests, and you don't wait for them to complete, which is another mistake. I'd suggest how check how Axios is tested.

Comment: It’s generally not advisable to use async in your tests and to use fakeAsync instead, though I’m not sure if this is acceptable for Vue testing. You should look into it, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Im not 100% sure why. but switching to `shallowMount` fixed the error.

Add `shallowMount` from vue test utils:

```
import {mount, shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils';
import Home2 from '@/views/Home2';
```

Then change `mount` to `shallowMount`:

```
describe('Home', () => {
    test('Example Test', async () => {
        // Arrange - Mounts the component so we can test it. And chooses what we are going to test in the component
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Home2)
        // Act - Does something to the component

        // Assert - Checks to see if what we did to the component matches what we want it to do
        expect(wrapper.html()).toContain(0)
    })
})
```

You can also just turn off logging with by running `--silent`. So run your test with the command `yarn:test --silent`

Comment: Most likely a sub component in Home2 is making a network request. `shallowMount` probably isn't the ideal solution. If you can share your code, I can help fix the original problem.